# MATLAB: periodogram Showing Error "Invalid Value for Data" for Certain Input

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

I am trying to use the command `periodogram` in MATLAB 15a.

My Periodogram code:

```
periodogram(Ts_outside)
```

When I replace `Ts_outside` with `Ts_inside`, it is working. But for the above code, it is showing the following set of errors (Please note that all the errors in the in-built files of MATLAB):

```
Error using dspdata/validatedata (line 14)
Invalid value for Data. Data must be a vector or matrix containing real, positive values.

Error in dspdata.abstractps/validatedata (line 8)
dspdata.validatedata(this,data);

Error in dspdata.abstractfreqresp/initialize>validate_data (line 77)
validatedata(this, data);

Error in dspdata.abstractfreqresp/initialize (line 23)
    [data, dataLen] = validate_data(this, data);

Error in dspdata.psd (line 82)
initialize(this,varargin{:});

Error in periodogram (line 197)
        hdspdata = dspdata.psd(Pxx,w{:},'SpectrumType',options.range);
```

I have checked for imaginary values in `Ts_outside`, by using command `imag`. Following is the result of that:

```
any(imag(Ts_outside))

ans =

     0
```

As you can see, its imaginary part has no non-zero element.

I don't know what is the problem with my variable. It is a 33119x1 matrix, just like `Ts_inside`. Also, the same set of errors is showing when I try to use `crosscorr` on it. What could be the possible source of error?

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if there is any `NaN` element in your `Ts_outside` vector:

```
any(isnan(Ts_outside))
```

Comment: it shows 1. But by visual inspection I cant find any

Comment: I found the entry which matlab thinks is NaN,but actually it's a real number. Anyway I replaced it with the same number and now it is working well.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer? I can't tell.

Comment: So, it looks like there is     NaN     element in the vector. As a result, Matlab function does not work. I would consider this as an answer

Comment: Interesting thing to know is, when you look at the all elements of vector,they are real number,but somehow matlab shows the vecor has one NaN.

Comment: you can use     find()    function to find the location of the NaN element.